# FENICSx or deal.ii for modeling fluid structure interaction of cylindrical energy harvesters in various arrangements

Tags: fluid-dynamics, solid-mechanics, computational-mechanics

I'm trying to model fluid-structure interaction of cylindrical energy harvesters in various arrangements. I have chosen OpenFOAM for the fluid part but I have no clue which framework to use for the solid modelling. The cylinders are supposed to be able to undergo large nonlinear deformations. I want to know which framework to use for the solid domain that would both be easy to couple with the fluid domain for multiple solid instances as well as easy to program in. So far, deal.ii and FENICSx look like good candidates on the precice website. Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that firstly depends on which element type you intend to use. If you are going to use shell/plate elements (which is common in cylinder analysis), deal.II does not have direct support for them. The same is not true for [FEniCS](https://fenics-shells.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Another candidate to consider is [Calculix](http://www.calculix.de/). It has support for shell elements, although when processing them, they are converted to solid elements. Unlike the above-mentioned programs, you do not need to 'program,' strictly speaking, as it is based on input files, which is pretty similar to Abaqus' .inp file. You just need to figure out how to write the input, and that's all. You do not need to write C++ or Python code to build your model, as is the case with deal.II and FEniCS.